# useSWR with getServerSideProps and GraphQL returns empty render when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: mongoose, next.js, graphql, swr

Currently I'm trying to make a page with Next.js with `pages/api` feature pointing to `graphql` with `graphql-yoga` dependency and getting the data from `mongoose` `http://localhost:3000/api/graphql`.

My goal is to make a SSR page with combining `getServerSideProps()` and `swr` for data fetcher to get data from GraphQL URL.

I successfully did that, but the problem is when I disable JavaScript (in Chrome) and then refresh the page the data and CSS is not rendering as expected.

**Before ( Javascript Enabled )**

[image]

**After ( Javascript Disabled )**

[image]

Here is my Source Code:

`pages/api/graphql.js`:

```
import { createServer } from '@graphql-yoga/node'
import resolvers from 'models/graphql/resolvers'
import typeDefs from 'models/graphql/typeDefs'
import dbConnect from '../../dbConnect'

dbConnect()
const server = createServer({
    schema: {
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
    },
    endpoint: '/api/graphql',
})

export default server
```

`dbConnect.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const MongoDb = process.env.MONGODB_URI

const connectDb = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(MongoDb, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
        console.log('db success connect')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error connecting to database')
        console.log(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

export default connectDb
```

`index.js`

```
import Home from "components/home";
import useSWR, { SWRConfig } from "swr";
import booksQuery from 'models/graphql/queries/books'

const graphqlUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/graphql";

const fetcher = (query) =>
    fetch(graphqlUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => json.data)


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const repoInfo = await fetcher(booksQuery);
    return {
        props: {
            fallback: {
                [graphqlUrl]: repoInfo
            }
        }
    };
}

function Repo() {
    const { data, error } = useSWR(booksQuery, fetcher);
    if (error) return "An error has occurred.";
    if (!data) return "Loading...";
    const { books} = data
    return <Home data={books} />

}

export default function Index({ fallback }) {
    return (
        <SWRConfig value={{fallback}}>
            <Repo />
        </SWRConfig>
    )
}
```

How did this happen and what is the solution to make the render the same as with JavaScript enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in the `useSWR` call needs to match the fallback key used in `getServerSideProps`.

In your case this means you should use the `booksQuery` value as a key rather than `graphqlUrl`, so it matches in both situations.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const repoInfo = await fetcher(booksQuery);
    return {
        props: {
            fallback: {
                [booksQuery]: repoInfo
            }
        }
    };
}
```

```js
const { data, error } = useSWR(booksQuery, fetcher);
//                             ^ Same key value as `fallback`. `data` will be populated correctly during SSR.
```

Answer (score 0):

When javascript in the browser is disabled, the contents loading from the server only works (SSR). The contents painted from the client side (dynamic DOM + CSS) won't work.

For better handling, you can show a message to the user using noscript. noscrirpt will run when javascript is disabled.

```
<noscript>
    <img src="no_js.gif" alt="Javascript not enabled" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: Hi Ahammed, sorry I edited the question. I mean What is the solution to make the render the same as with Javascript Enabled ?

Comment: In SSR, only the first rendering is done by the server, which returns plain HTML content together with the js that will be used for the subsequent rendering. if JS is disabled the page is a static HTML so basically no, in this scenario there's no way to interact with the page.

Comment: Hi Ahammed, actually I tried using new api `pages/api/rest` and try to fetch the data directly with `mongoose` not with the help of `graphql-yoga` as I did above. It get succeed to get the data after Javascript is Disabled.  Probably this `graphql-yoga` is interrupting it ?

Comment: Did you use `useSWR` in that case? I believe it is the problem with `useSWR` since `graphql-yoga` is running at the server level

Comment: Yes Ahammed, I also use `useSWR` for case `pages/api/rest`